# how to set point one variants difference in NumberPicker in android as mention below ?

Tags: android, android-activity, numberpicker

how to set point one variants difference in NumberPicker in android?

can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) library for this purpose it was very handy to me.
Particularly [this](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers/blob/master/sample%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fdoomonafireball%2Fbetterpickers%2Fsample%2Factivity%2Fnumberpicker%2FSampleNumberWithOptions.java) sample will help to do it.
This method should do it:

```
setDecimalVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Common dialog:

```
NumberPickerBuilder npb = new NumberPickerBuilder()
                            .setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager())
                            .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment_Light)
                            .setPlusMinusVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
                            .setDecimalVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                            .setReference(BUTTON_ONE_REFERENCE)
                            .setLabelText("LBS.");
                    if (mMin != null) {
                        npb.setMinNumber(mMin);
                    }
                    if (mMax != null) {
                        npb.setMaxNumber(mMax);
                    }
                    npb.show();
```

Comment: Thanx for your valuable help... :)

Comment: I think its not possible for me to add around 8 MB Android-BetterPickers.zip in my project.

Is this possible without adding library?

Comment: Library is - 1.6 mb. Also you can extract only views which you looking for and abandon other res and src.